# Rustlang: Adding a return statement in a macro

Tags: rust, macros, return, rust-macros

I'm going through the rustlings course in order to learn rustlang and I'm working on quiz 4.  The following is the solution I found.

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($val:expr) => {
       format!("Hello {}", $val)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_my_macro_world() {
        assert_eq!(my_macro!("world!"), "Hello world!");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_my_macro_goodbye() {
        assert_eq!(my_macro!("goodbye!"), "Hello goodbye!");
    }
}
```

But before this, I unsuccessfully tried the following:

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($val:expr) => {
       return format!("Hello {}", $val)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_my_macro_world() {
        assert_eq!(my_macro!("world!"), "Hello world!");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_my_macro_goodbye() {
        assert_eq!(my_macro!("goodbye!"), "Hello goodbye!");
    }
}
```

The only difference in this non-working solution being the `return` keyword.  In this case, the compiler spits out a whole list of errors and warnings.

Why is this not correct?  Are return statements not allowed from within a rust macro?

Comment: return requires a semi-colon.

Comment: @STR_ZBR No it doesn't – in Rust, `return` is an expression, not a statement. `foo(return 5);` is valid syntax (albeit meaningless).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a macro, its body is pasted* into the place where it's called.

This means that in the second snippet, this:

```
#[test]
fn test_my_macro_world() {
    assert_eq!(my_macro!("world!"), "Hello world!");
}
```

is expanded to this:

```
#[test]
fn test_my_macro_world() {
    assert_eq!(return format!("Hello {}", "world!"), "Hello world!");
}
```

which causes a type error.

---

* It's a bit more complicated than that: there's some [magic](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-hygiene.html) that prevents naming collisions as well.